# Why does the cast operator attempt to call the constructor first?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, casting

I have an object that stores some state in a member of type `S`. Upon request of the `view` method, it returns a view of it of the type `T`, obtaining it by casting.

```
template<typename S, typename T>
struct Viewer {
    S m_state;
    Viewer(const S& state): m_state(state) {}
    auto view() {
        // return m_state.operator T();
        return static_cast<T>(m_state);
    }
};

int main() {
    Viewer<double, double> v(1.);
    std::cout << v.view() << std::endl;
}
```

Let's suppose that the object is made like this:

```
#include <tuple>
struct State: std::tuple<int, int> {
    template<typename T>
    State(const T& t) { std::get<0>(*this) = std::get<1>(*this) = t; }
    template<typename T>
    State(const T& t1, const T& t2) {
        std::get<0>(*this) = t1;
        std::get<1>(*this) = t2;
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const State& s) {
    return os << std::get<0>(s) << " " << std::get<1>(s);
}

struct Wrapper {
    State m_state;
    Wrapper(const State& initial_state): m_state(initial_state) {}
    operator State() const { return m_state; }  // Conversion operator
};


int main() {
    State s(0, 1);
    Wrapper w(s);
    Viewer<Wrapper, State> v(w);
    std::cout << v.view() << std::endl;  // <<< Error
}
```

By compiling this code now I get the error

```
error: cannot convert ‘const Wrapper’ to ‘std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<int, int> >’ {aka ‘int’} in assignment
State(const T& t) { std::get<0>(*this) = std::get<1>(*this) = t; }
```

Basically `static_cast<T>(m_state)` is trying to perform the cast by calling the constructor of the object of type `T` (with `T=State`), passing to it `m_state` (which is of type `Wrapper`) as the only argument. Since `T` has a template constructor that takes a single argument, it gets called. However the assignment fails because that constructor was not intended to work with an object of type `Wrapper`.
By dropping the constructor `template<typename T> State(const T& t);` from the `State` class the problem gets solved, because `static_cast` can no longer find a valid constructor to call. However, I need that constructor, and I cannot simply remove it.

If I explicitly call the cast operator in the `Viewer::view` method, the code runs again

```
    return m_state.operator T();
```

However, it no longer works for a `Viewer<double, double>` object, because `double` does not have the member `operator double`

```
error: request for member ‘operator double’ in ‘((Viewer<double, double>*)this)->Viewer<double, double>::m_state’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
```

And I also need the Viewer class to work by instantiating it with `<double, double>`.

I don't want to specialize the `State` class constructor, because it should be unaware of the `Wrapper` class: what if a second wrapper class was created? Would it be necessary to specialize the state constructor further? Also, I prefer not to have specializations for the `Viewer` class. Again, what would happen if you created multiple wrapper classes? Or if you used it with an object without an explicit conversion operator?

I think the best solution is that the casting operation does not try to call the constructor when a suitable operator is available, however I have no idea how to do that. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If I'm following this correctly, your `State(const T& t)` constructor is really there to convert primitive types to `int` values, which you assign to each of the two tuple elements. So, `T` must be convertible to `int`. And when you wrap the `State` in your `Viewer`, your constructor template expands to `State(const Wrapper&)`. Because `Wrapper` is not implicitly convertible to `int`, it's an error. But you're expecting the wrapper to implicitly convert to `State`. I think the issue is template matching rules will match the function template with a higher precedence than implicit conversion.

Comment: Note that you do not need the `Viewer` class to reproduce the issue. Simply `std::cout << State(w);` is sufficient.

Comment: Essentially, `static_cast<T>(m_state)` converts the *value* of `m_state` to `T`.  To do that it initialises a separate instance of `T` which, for a class type, means calling a constructor.  If you don't want that, change your `view()` function and the conversion so it produces a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specialize the `State` constructor, but do something else to *SFINEA out* the constructor template so that the default copy constructor is called in this case.

```cpp
struct State: std::tuple<int, int> {
    template<typename T,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, int>>>
    State(const T& t) {
        std::get<0>(*this) = std::get<1>(*this) = t;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f8Er9s9TY)

Without the `std::enable_if` part, the constructor template is instantiated with `T=Wrapper` when resolution begins. `State(const Wrapper&)` is added to the candidate set as a non-template function and is preferred over the predefined copy or move constructor that you expect.